# GridView control fail to find the id when update

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, datagridview

I'm writing the following code to update SQL Server. I received the following error message:

> Incorrect syntax near '-'. Must declare the scalar variable "@id".
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near '-'. Must declare the scalar variable "@id".
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '-'. Must declare
>   the scalar variable "@id".]

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="E-mail" HeaderText="E-mail" SortExpression="E-mail" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:demoConnectionString4 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [de]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [de] SET [Name]=@Name, [E-mail]=@column1 WHERE [id]=@id">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="column1" Type="String"/>
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Use datafeild for id also and instead of doing commands hardcoded in try to handle it on onclick of update button event

Comment: It might be the field name "E-mail". Are hyphens "-" allowed in field names in your version of SQL?

Answer (score 1):

The error is on the ID TemplateField, you use a `Label` on `EditItemTemplate` to show the ID, and this label **is not post back that ID** that is needed for the sql update. The `asp:label` is not render an input field that is needed here.

Either remove the TemplateField, and just use as the rest fields an `asp:BoundField` that automatically creates input fields when you update each line, either you make it a `read only text box` (on `EditImteTemplate`) so can post the id.

This lines are what you need to focus and change:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```